# Entity Framework Stored Procedures Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, stored-procedures

I have the following Entity Framework model:

[image: Entities]

It's a very simple model and was working fine when Entity Framework was generating the SQL. When I mapped the entities to stored procedures I get the following error when trying to create a `LogEntry`:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

The code I am using to make a LogEntry looks like the following:

```
le.DateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
le.User = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

Log log = lr.GetLog(le.LogId);
log.LogEntries.Add(le);

lr.Save(); // lr is an instance of LogsRepository, defined earlier in the class
```

The exception isn't thrown until `lr.Save()` is called.

Can anybody help me decipher this? I have stored procedures which **all work on their own, independent of entity framework**, mapped to the entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure out what was causing the error. Take a look at the following mapping setup:

[image: Log Mapping]

As you can see, I had a result column binding from `UpdateLog`, problem being that `UpdateLog` doesn't return anything. I accidentally put this into the mapping. After deleting the result column binding everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're using the stored procedure. If you add a function import for the procedure, you can call the function import directly on the context.

Comment: I mapped the stored procedures to the entities in the entity designer according to the following screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/em6YK

This has worked fine in the past. I only use function imports for select operations.