# Can I bind a constant to an Entity Framework insert / update function mapping?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

We are in the process of upgrading a legacy system which had a custom ORM to use EF 4.3.

The legacy system makes use of hybrid 'Save' Stored Procedures, whereby the proc itself determines whether to insert or update an entity, based on the existence of a primary key, along the lines of:

```
-- Hybrid Insert if not exist / Update if does exist
CREATE PROC dbo.SaveEntity
        @EntityId INT = NULL, -- This field is specified on an update, 
                              -- and left to its default on inserts
        @Field1 NVARCHAR(50)
        -- @Field2 etc etc
AS
    BEGIN
        -- IF Exists (Entity with PK @EntityId) then insert ...
        --   BEGIN
        --     INSERT INTO Entity(Field1, ...) VALUES (@Field1, ...)
        --     SELECT @EntityId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()    
        --   END
        -- ELSE
        --   BEGIN
        --     UPDATE Entity SET Field1 = @Field1, ... WHERE EntityId = @EntityId
        --   END

        -- Return the PK Here
        SELECT @EntityId AS EntityId
    END
```

In EF, I've added the 'save' stored procedures to the model and mapped both the Insert and Update functions to the 'save' proc in the Mapping details for the respective entities.

The Update function works fine - since the return result doesn't change, it doesn't need to be mapped back to the Entity.

However, I've got into a catch-22 situation with the Insert mapping. For the Insert function, I need to map the assigned PK Identity value returned by the SProc back to the Entity PK. However, because of the nature of the Proc (which has the optional @EntityId parameter), EF also requires all parameters to be mapped, even though @EntityId is optional and defaulted.

If I fail to map EntityId to the PROC field, then I get a compile error:

```
A mapping function bindings specifies a function Model.Store.SaveEntity 
but does not map the following function parameters: EntityId
```

And if I bind the EntityId to the proc field AND as a Result Column bindings, I get the run time error (because a field can be only one of input or output mapping, but [not both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655434/entity-framework-stored-procedures-exception)):

```
Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. 
Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, 
or store-generated values.
```

So my question is, *how do I get around this situation?*. e.g. Is there any way for me to bind a constant (i.e. ZERO or NULL) to my Insert Proc field mapping?

**Please Note** : Some of these procs have additional logic in them (housekeeping, auditing, etc) so I am reluctant to ditch them entirely, or rewrite the PROCS into separate INSERT / UPDATE procs, as they are well proven and changing the underlying DB DDL is not part of the mandate for our upgrade.

Comment: You can always write an update (or insert) sproc as a very thin wrapper around the insert/update sproc.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks - good point. I will try an insert wrapper which just returns the PK and let you know. But I can't believe there isn't a way to get EF to ignore / default the mapping?